# Why debug messages about rw-semaphore don't print out in the linux kernel?

Tags: debugging, kernel, config, semaphore

I'm trying to output debug messages about rw-semaphores in the Linux kernel. I enabled CONFIG_DEBUG_RWSEMS in the configure file. But the messages don't output.

```
# define DEBUG_RWSEMS_WARN_ON(c, sem)   
do {            \
    if (!debug_locks_silent &&              \
WARN_ONCE(c, "DEBUG_RWSEMS_WARN_ON(%s): count = 0x%lx, magic = 0x%lx, owner = 0x%lx, curr 0x%lx, list %sempty\n",\
#c, atomic_long_read(&(sem)->count),        \
(unsigned long) sem->magic,         \
atomic_long_read(&(sem)->owner), (long)current, \
list_empty(&(sem)->wait_list) ? "" : "not "))   \
     debug_locks_off();         \
    } while (0)
#else
# define DEBUG_RWSEMS_WARN_ON(c, sem)
```

What option I  can forgot to add in the config?

Comment: "I enabled CONFIG_DEBUG_RWSEMS in the configure file" - And you have rebuilt the **entire kernel**, right? Note also, that after a lock-related warning is emitted, further warnings becomes usually disabled (`debug_locks_off`). So you need to carefully check `dmesg` output for any warnings.

Comment: Yes, I do. I rebuilt whole kernel.